# Wordpress custom fields hook not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add more fields to a product on Wordpress (Woocommerce).
I have added the html fields like so:

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="g/w/l_prijs" type="text" placeholder="g/w/l prijs" width="10"></td>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="t/t/i_prijs" type="text" placeholder="Telefoon/tv/internet prijs" width="10"></td>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="heffingen_prijs" type="text" placeholder="Heffingen prijs" width="10"></td>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="verzekering_prijs" type="text" placeholder="Woonverzekering prijs" width="10"></td>
</tr>
```

I'm using a hook to save this information to the database but I can't get it to work.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wc_prices_save_product' );
function wc_prices_save_product( $pID ) {
global $globals;
// If this is a auto save do nothing, we only save when update button is clicked
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) { return; }
    add_post_meta( $pID, 'g/w/l_prijs', $_POST['g/w/l_prijs'], true ) || update_post_meta( $pID, 'g/w/l_prijs', $_POST['g/w/l_prijs'] ); 
    add_post_meta( $pID, 't/t/i_prijs', $_POST['t/t/i_prijs'], true ) || update_post_meta( $pID, 't/t/i_prijs', $_POST['t/t/i_prijs'] ); 
    add_post_meta( $pID, 'heffingen_prijs', $_POST['heffingen_prijs'], true ) || update_post_meta( $pID, 'heffingen_prijs', $_POST['heffingen_prijs'] ); 
    add_post_meta( $pID, 'verzekering_prijs', $_POST['verzekering_prijs'], true ) || update_post_meta( $pID, 'verzekering_prijs', $_POST['verzekering_prijs'] );
}
?>
```

Am I missing something? It seems pretty straightforward but it doesn't seem to save anything. Or it's not showing the saved information in the fields for some reason.

Comment: Whats `$globals` by the way?

Comment: 1) Why are you using add_post_meta and update_post_meta if you can only use update_post_meta? 2) Can it be that that the condition returns always true and that's why the values are not being added to the database?

Comment: Also you don't need to use `add_post_meta` if it doesn't exist `update_post_meta` will add it for you.

Comment: Maybe I need to get the value from the database and show it in the input fields? Where could I find the values in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While saving the post, there is no need of add_post_meta(), as update_post_meta() will create meta field if not present or update the existing meta field, if it is present.

For display in dashboard, you need to extract these metafields values and display them.

For example,

In meta box, callback function, where you have added, extra fields

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="g/w/l_prijs" type="text" placeholder="g/w/l prijs" width="10"></td>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="t/t/i_prijs" type="text" placeholder="Telefoon/tv/internet prijs" width="10"></td>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="heffingen_prijs" type="text" placeholder="Heffingen prijs" width="10"></td>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="verzekering_prijs" type="text" placeholder="Woonverzekering prijs" width="10"></td>
</tr>
```

Use the below code,

```
global $post;

<tr>
    <td><input class="backend_price_accommodatie" name="g/w/l_prijs" type="text" placeholder="g/w/l prijs" width="10" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'g/w/l_prijs', true); ?>"></td>

...

</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a hunch it was something like this. I tried looking in the database if it was being updated but couldn't find the fields :/.

Comment: You can find the metafield value in "wp_postmeta" table.

Just try this query :

SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` like '%g/w/l_prijs%'

in your database.